# Scope in Javascript callback

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I expect to see the array `["foo", "bar"]` at the second `console.log(this.items)`. But instead, I get `undefined`.

[Here is the jsBin](http://jsbin.com/hodegimohu/edit?html,console,output).

How do I get `["foo", "bar"]` instead of `undefined`?

http://jsbin.com/hodegimohu/edit?html,console,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">
<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-element',
      properties: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          value: ['foo','bar']
        },
      },
      ready: function(){
        console.log(this.items) // ["foo", "bar"]
        google.charts.load('current', {
          'packages': ['geochart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this._drawRegionsMap);
      },
      _drawRegionsMap: function() {
        console.log(this.items); // undefined
      },
    });
  })();
</script>
</dom-module>
<x-element></x-element>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.bind`.

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this._drawRegionsMap.bind(this));
```

Nothing more than appropriately handling the callback (Nothing polymer based).